# PHP function include -> site not loading

Tags: php, function

when I try to call a function that is included a few rows above the whole site  isnt able to reload.

```
$object = 'termin';
$cache_available = check_cache($object);
```

That´s how i call the function and the defintion look like this:

```
function check_cache($object){
    $file = '../../cache/' . $object . '.json';
    if(file_exists($file)){
        $time_cache = date ("H:i:s", filemtime($file));
        $time_now = date ("h:i:sa");
        $diff = strtotime($time_now) - strtotime($time_cache);

        if($diff <= 60) {return true; } //Neu genug
        else            {return false;} //Zu alt
    }
    return false;
}
```

Can someone tell me what causes the error.

Explanation of not loading:
---When i navigate to the folder in my browser (localhost, xampp) and click on the file to open it loads for a short time but then displays the directory again.

Comment: You need to debug your code,  find the error and paste in your question. We won't help you debug. No

Comment: *click on the file* What file? termin.json or the php one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the unit for $diff is seconds. Could it be that your display of the file is dependant upon this function evaluating to true and that is only the case for one minute after writing the file to the cache? I really don't have enough information to go on here but that code should work as intended. I tested your function and it works as expected on my machine. Can we see the code for the page that where it is going back to the directory after a period of time? I still did not really understand what you were saying with that.

Can be cleaned up a bit here are my suggestions & sorry to be that guy.

```
function check_cache($object)
{
    $file = '../../cache/' . $object . '.json';
    if(file_exists($file)){
        $time_cache = date ("H:i:s", filemtime($file));
        return strtotime("now") - strtotime($time_cache) <= 60;
    }
    return false;
}
```

or

```
function check_cache($object)
{
    $file = '../../cache/' . $object . '.json';
    return file_exists($file) ? strtotime("now") - filemtime($file) <= 60 : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That check_cache does not look right. It has wrong path checking to begin with and a to long return statement. With if and else. I rewrote it, try it and see if it works.

```
function check_cache($object) {
    $file = __DIR__ . '/../../cache/' . $object . '.json';

    if(file_exists($file)){
        $time_cache = date ("H:i:s", filemtime($file));
        $time_now = date("H:i:s");
        $diff = strtotime($time_now) - strtotime($time_cache);

        return $diff <= 60;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First your filemtime() function needs to be debugged to see if possible error could be found.

Secondly, your file path could be the problem

Thirdly, Your time format do not correlate. I recommend you use the same format i.e

```
$time_cache = date ("H:i:s", filemtime($file));
    $time_now = date ("H:i:s");//the a has been removed
    $diff = strtotime($time_now) - strtotime($time_cache);
```

Comment: h must be uppercase in `date ("h:i:s");`